# How to change the font of static text control (winapi)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dialog

I'm currently using winapi with C++ to make a program. When I was using the rc editor in Visual Stdio 2015 (the control is on a dialog), I found that there's no font changer for static text control. So, How to change the font of static text control (winapi)?

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible to change the font of a static control by modifying the resource file. You can only change the font of the whole dialog.

You can change the font of a static control in runtime, by sending the [`WM_SETFONT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632642.aspx) message. A font can be created by the [`CreateFontIndirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183500.aspx) function, for example.

Comment: Gonna to try that now