# How to change the font style of the text of a common control like button, label, etc. in c++ using GDI+?

Tags: visual-c++, fonts, visual-studio-2019, gdi+, common-controls

I am trying to change the font style of a button using GDI+ but I don't know how to do it.

My button -

```
HWND btn = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"My button", WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON, 50, 50, 100, 300, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I have initialized GDI+ -

```
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
```

And also Shutdown it -

```
GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

Any help please

Comment: Those controls don't use GDI+. To change the font, you need to use HFONT.

Comment: Please tell me how to use it. I know something about WM_SETFONT but don't know how to use it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the font of static text control (winapi)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855175/how-to-change-the-font-of-static-text-control-winapi)

Comment: Yes, thanks but how to use WM_SETFONT in window messages?

Means like this  - `case WM_SETFONT {}`

Comment: You can just search for `WM_SETFONT` to [find examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651569/changing-the-font-size-of-a-static-textbox-in-a-windows-gui).

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651569/changing-the-font-size-of-a-static-textbox-in-a-windows-gui) - This really helped me. Thanks for sharing with me

Comment: If found my answer, thanks again

Comment: Please post the answer and accept it, so that others with the same problem will have the answer.

Comment: Sure! I will definitely add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common controls don't use GDI+. You need use LOGFONT.

```
HWND TextBox;
TextBox = CreateWindowW(WC_EDIT, L"", WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 330, 130, 300, 100, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

LOGFONT logfont; 
ZeroMemory(&logfont, sizeof(LOGFONT));

logfont.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET; //Font
logfont.lfHeight = 20; //Font Height
logfont.lfWidth = 23; //Font Width
logfont.lfWeight = 300; //Font Weight

//If want
logfont.lfItalic = true; // Italic (Boolean)
logfont.lfUnderline = true; // Underline (Boolean)


HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&logfont);   
SendMessage(TextBox, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, TRUE);
```